# Configurable and Writable Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently taking the curve in learning OOP in Javascript and I came to this confusion

```
var person={
  name:"kevin",
};

Object.defineProperty(person,"name",{
  enumerable:false,
  configurable:true,
  writable:false,
});

delete person.name;
person.name="blue";
alert(person.name);
```

As you see the writable is set to `false` and configurable is set to `true` and even vice - versa still it changes the name from `"Kevin"` to "Blue".

Why did the name changes if writable is false? Kindly please explain clearly

[Link for the code](http://jsbin.com/didaxakumobu/1/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a literal property `name` in your object, and then you're using `Object.defineProperty` on top of it.

Do it like this

```
var person = {};

Object.defineProperty(person, "name", {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: true,
  writable: false
});

// this does nothing
person.name = "kevin";

// see? still undefined
console.log(person.name); // undefined
```

---

I think this is a better approach altogether

```
// "Person" constructor
function Person(name) {
  Object.defineProperty(this, "name", {
    configurable: true,
    get: function() { return name; },
    set: function(newName) { return name = newName; }
  });
}

// init with name
var person = new Person("kevin");

// check it
console.log(person.name); // "kevin"

// set a name
person.name = "kevin2";

// check it
console.log(person.name); // "kevin2"

// delete the name property
delete person.name;

// check again
console.log(person.name); // undefined
```

Comment: This only works because you removed the line `delete person.name;` in the original code

Answer (score 2):

Since you set the property to `configurable:true` you are able to delete it.

After you call `delete person.name;` the name property is gone.

Then when you call `person.name="blue";` 
a new property is create which is writable by default

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an object first and then defining the property when the property is already there. 
You need to have code like this inorder to avoid Kevin being changed:

```
var person={};

Object.defineProperty(person,"name",{
  value:"kevin",
  enumerable:false,
  configurable:false,
  writable:false,
});

delete person.name;
person.name="blue";
alert(person.name);
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/210720d3abdea1224cd6.git)

Comment: This code works have tested in JSBin as well. Do not knw why this has not been marked as an answer when it was answered first.

Answer (score 1):

See [Section 8.12.9](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.9) of the [ECMAScript® Language Specification (5.1)](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/)

Notice the NOTE at the bottom of this section:

> NOTE Step 10.b allows any field of Desc to be different from the
>   corresponding field of current if current’s [[Configurable]] field is
>   true. This even permits changing the [[Value]] of a property whose
>   [[Writable]] attribute is false. This is allowed because a true
>   [[Configurable]] attribute would permit an equivalent sequence of
>   calls where [[Writable]] is first set to true, a new [[Value]] is set,
>   and then [[Writable]] is set to false.

That also applies to being able to delete a configurable property, allowing you to redefine it with a different value.